# Utility "dar" tries to read files and directories not specified (using only --include-from-file)

Tags: backup, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The PC of my colleague died a few days ago, and so I decided it was time for me to setup a "backup strategy". We are on Windows PCs, but with WSL, I get most of the Linux commands as well, so I decided to try using "dar" to make backups. I have never used "dar" before, so idk if this problem is specific to "dar" in WSL.

What I do is run multiple commands like this, to find the files:

`find '/mnt/c/Users/username/Documents' -type f`

Pipe it all in one big file, and call dar with it:

`dar -v -e -m 256 -z -s 1G -D -R / -c`date -I`_data -Z "*.gz" -Z "*.7z" -Z "*.bz2" -Z "*.zip" -Z "*.png" -Z "*.jpg" -Z "*.bak" -Z "*.dat" --include-from-file files_to_backup.txt`

I've included the full command, as idk which part might be causing trouble.

And here is my problem: I only select *files* using find (-type f), but then get errors like this:

- Cannot read directory contents: /mnt/c/Config.Msi : Error opening directory in furtive read mode: /mnt/c/Config.Msi : Permission denied
- Error reading inode of file /mnt/c/swapfile.sys : Permission denied
- Error reading directory contents: Cannot read file information for /mnt/c/Users/username/SendTo : Permission denied . Ignoring file or directory

Nowhere in files_to_backup.txt does it say "/mnt/c/Config.Msi" or "/mnt/c/swapfile.sys" or just "/mnt/c" or just "/Users/username". files_to_backup.txt only contains *filenames* and not the files that dar is complaining about.

So, how do I stop dar from trying to read files/directories that are *not* listed in the --include-from-file parameter?

Note: I cannot add the "dar" tag, as it doesn't exist, and I don't have the rep to create tags.

Comment: Why `-R /`? And if your `find` does not contain any special rules why not let `dar`?

Comment: Also with `-va` what does it say regarding selected or skipped files?

Comment: "-R /" was in the example I followed, but that was for a full backup. I thought I needed that, to make sure all file names are "full". My "find" calls do contain "special rules", just not the one example I gave. What they all have in common is the "-type f". I will now check what "-va" says.... It doesn't like "-va": "Parse error: Invalid argument for -v option"

Comment: Without "-R /", dar seems to do nothing ("0" for all stats). I also tried removing "-D"; that did not prevent  the error messages.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used `dar` and it just seems to walk through / fly by  / stat files *before* checking them against the include file list, hence you get such error messages. I guess that's what it means by these being "filters" instead of literally just picking up the listed files.

Comment: I would not trust in a utility like `dar`. Why not use a utility that has been tested thoroughly enough?

Comment: @schily Having no personal recommendation, I chose the first solution I found, that seemed to work for me. You could suggest a "more renowned" program.

Comment: I recommend star from the schilytools. See http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/